# Effects of the Stack Exchange 'update to Terms of Service' on MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, support

Do the recent [changes to Stack Exchange Terms of Service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309746/a-new-2018-update-to-our-terms-of-service-is-here?cb=1) affect MathOverflow in any way -- and if yes, what are the concrete effects?

Comment: the arbitration clause produced quite an uproar --- https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309797/were-examining-the-implementation-of-arbitration-in-the-2018-tos-update/309804#309804

Comment: @CarloBeenakker: Does this clause apply to MathOverflow as well?

Comment: I'm pretty certain it does, AFAIK it's for the entire Stack Exchange ecosystem.

Comment: It sure does. Just scroll to the bottom of the page to read the Terms of Service that are in effect.

Comment: The complete agreement between the MathOverflow corporation and Stack Exchange, Inc. is [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9bqmDNwzTjkMjRHVkNRa1ZzQmc/edit). I don't see anything which would prohibit SE from changing the ToS on this site (which it operates). A separate question is whether the MathOverflow corporation itself is bound to the new ToS; hopefully the owners of the site contact their lawyers and opt out of arbitration clause if it does apply.

Comment: Do you wish to ask if it affects Mathoverflow *users* like you and me, or if it affects Mathoverflow the legal entity? Because I think that the answer is different.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Actually both.

Comment: The [SE response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/310061/electronic-opt-out-correcting-miscommunication-and-additional-questions-answer?cb=1) to the "arbitration clause" uproar sounds reasonable to me. Presumably if they would have argued their motives from the outset the response would have been more encouraging.